# Interface 'App\Jobs\SelfHandling' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I got this error when update from laravel 5.1 to 5.4:

> Interface 'App\Jobs\SelfHandling' not found

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably adding this interface to your codebase will help

Comment: Apparently not correctly added if you still see the error. Check the use statments in the class that is using this interface. Interface might be wrongly imported

Comment: @flower Show class and interface codes here. Also tell us the paths for those two.

Comment: use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;

class GetRouteForecast extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue